# jQuery calculation query

Tags: jquery, formula

I'm currently working on a calculator for a clients website to show some totals based on some figures that are inputted into form areas.

Below is the code I'm working on so far:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#calculator_form_metre").submit(function() {
    var area = (($("#area_width").val() * $("#area_unit").val()) * ($("#area_length").val() * $("#area_unit").val()));
    var bronze = (area * 1) * 2.8
    var silver = (area * 1) * 4.52
    var gold = (area * 1) * 5.06
    var platinum = (area * 1) * 5.52

    $("#bronze").val(Math.round(bronze * 120) / 100);
    $("#silver").val(Math.round(silver * 120) / 100);
    $("#gold").val(Math.round(gold * 120) / 100);
    $("#platinum").val(Math.round(platinum * 120) / 100);

    return false;
  })
})
```

I'm able to generate the correct figures but the client wants to show a specific figure of 78.00 if any figure totals to be less than that figure. I'm thinking it needs a condition of 'if' added somehow but I'm not sure how best to do this? Does anyone have any ideas that might help?

Comment: Are you saying that one of those values should always be a minimum of `78`, regardless of what the user enters? If so, which value?

Comment: Essentially the calculator works out a cost based on a width x height and gives a figure based on the level of service required. The level of service has a different figure as shown but essentially they have a min charge of 78 so if any figure is less than that figure they want the figures displayed to be 78, any calculation higher than that needs to show whatever the calculation is. If any figure is less than 78 it needs to show 78 if it's more then it needs to show the figure calculated. This would apply to all the fields.

Comment: Right, but what values? The `area`? `bronze`, `silver` etc? Or the end results placed in to `#bronze`, `#silver`...?

Comment: So you just want something like `var mincost = 78;` `if (bronze < mincost) bronze = mincost;` ? or even `var bronze = Math.max((area * 1) * 2.8, mincost);` ?

Comment: So the end results in #bronze, #silver etc. This is where the end calculation spits out

Comment: I'm not sure that would work (unless I'm not reading it correctly) The total needs to show 78 if it's less than 78, not 78 plus whatever the calculation is?

Comment: Apologies, I think I have misread that message and not allowed for the calculation that follows. I think this might just work for me

Comment: Could you advise on how to print the pounds and pence as the result? the amends work but the calculation shows as 78 and I would ideally like it to show 78.00?